# how to count number of days between dates using reactjs and validating firstdate is lessthan seconddate

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react trying to add description, startdate and todate in a table and trying to add days between dates,and storing it in Days field. Entered Fromdate is lessthan todate. i can't able to find count for number of days in reactjs code. please suggest me

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Button,Table,Input, Form, Row, Col} from 'reactstrap';

    class Products extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //  this.state.products = [];
        this.state = {};
        this.state.filterText = "";
        this.state.products = [

        ];

      }

      handleUserInput(filterText) {
        this.setState({filterText: filterText});
      };

      handleRowDel(product) {
        var index = this.state.products.indexOf(product);
        this.state.products.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState(this.state.products);
      };

      handleAddEvent(evt) {
        var id = (+ new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)).toString(36);
        var product = {
          id: id,
          description: "",
         fromdate: "",
          todate: "",
         totaldays:0 
        }
        this.state.products.push(product);
        this.setState(this.state.products);

      }

      handleProductTable(evt) {
        var item = {
          id: evt.target.id,
          name: evt.target.description,
          value: evt.target.value
        };
        var products = this.state.products;

        var newProducts = products.map(function(product) {
          for (var key in product) {
            if (key == item.name && product.id == item.id) {
              product[key] = item.value;

            }
          }
          return product;
        });
        this.setState(newProducts);
        console.log(this.state.products);
      };
      render() {

        return (
          <div>

            <ProductTable onProductTableUpdate={this.handleProductTable.bind(this)} onRowAdd={this.handleAddEvent.bind(this)} onRowDel={this.handleRowDel.bind(this)} products={this.state.products} filterText={this.state.filterText}/>
          </div>
        );

      }

    }


    class ProductTable extends React.Component {

      render() {
        var onProductTableUpdate = this.props.onProductTableUpdate;
        var rowDel = this.props.onRowDel;
        var filterText = this.props.filterText;

        var product = this.props.products.map(function(product) {
          if (product.description.indexOf(filterText) === -1) {
            return;
          }
          return (<ProductRow onProductTableUpdate={onProductTableUpdate} product={product} onDelEvent={rowDel.bind(this)} key={product.id}/>)
        });
        return (
          <div>
```

by using "+" button i am adding rows in a table, as shown in figure attached[by clicking add symbol rows are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/233U0.png)

```
          <Button type="button"  size="xl" color="success" onClick={this.props.onRowAdd} className="btn btn-success pull-right">+</Button>

            <Table striped>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Holiday List</th>
                   <th>From</th>
                   <th>To</th>
                   <th>totaldays</th>
                   <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
```

displays the table content
                  
                    {product}

```
              </tbody>

            </Table>
          </div>
        );

      }

    }

    class ProductRow extends React.Component {
      onDelEvent() {
        this.props.onDelEvent(this.props.product);

      }
      render() {

        return (
          <tr>
            <EditableCell1 onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              "type": "description",
              value: this.props.product.description,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell2 onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "fromdate",
              value: this.props.product.fromdate,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell3 onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "todate",
              value: this.props.product.todate,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell4 onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "totaldays",
              value: this.props.product.totaldays,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/> 



            <td >
             <Button
               onClick={this.onDelEvent.bind(this)}  >X</Button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );

      }




    }
```

cell for adding fromdate

```
     class EditableCell2 extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <td>
           <Input type='date' name="fromdate" />
          </td>
        );

      }

    }
```

cell for adding dates

```
    class EditableCell3 extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <td>
           <Input type='date' name="todate" onFocus={ this.onFocus }/>
          </td>
        );

      }

    }
```

cell for adding content

```
    class EditableCell1 extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <td id="desc">
            <Input type='text' name="description" />

          </td>
        );

      }

    }
```

cell for total count of days between dates

```
    class EditableCell4 extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <td id="desc">
            <Input type='text' name="totaldays"  />
          </td>
        );

      }


    }

    export default Products;
```

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I couldn't understand your question properly, I would suggest to use moment js which has a huge library for handling date and time related functions. You can npm install and import it. Can you please elaborate the question.